# MFMailComposeViewController and dark bar's tintColor in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a problem with changing tintColor of MFMailComposeViewController's navigation bar.
Exemplary I'm setting
`mailComposer.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

In effect the color isn't white, but it's like white with some alpha over black. The same with any other color. Is there any way to make the tintColor of items solid?

Preview here >>> http://cl.ly/image/1k1O3q251y2R

I wanted to customize the buttons to have them like rest of UI, but I cannot.

I suppose it came with iOS 7.1, before this version it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: I tried this - with whiteColor or blackColor - it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

in ios 7 set to barTintColor

```
mailComposer.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: I tried this - with whiteColor or blackColor - it doesn't change anything.